# How can I create one large Bitmap from lots of smaller ones in code?

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap

```
for (int i = 0; i < mYTileCount; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mXTileCount; j++) {
                int num = mTileGrid[j][i];
                canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mTileArray[num],              mTileSize, mTileSize, false), mXOffset, mYOffset, mPaint);
                mXOffset+=mTileSize;
            }
            mXOffset = 0;
            mYOffset+=mTileSize;
        }
```

this is the code im using to draw multiple bitmaps onto a canvas to create a tilemap, but instead of the canvas.drawbitmap thing i want to make a large bitmap from them instead

Answer (score 0):

Use a Canvas backed by a bitmap.  Create a new bitmap of the correct size, then call new Canvas(newBitmap) to create a Canvas that draws to that new Bitmap.  Then use the code you posted above with that canvas.

Answer (score 0):

If all of your bitmaps tile perfectly into a rectangular area, you could create a new Bitmap at the desired dimension that fits each of the smaller Bitmaps, then just copy the pixels from each smaller Bitmap into the larger one at the correct offsets.  You could do this with getPixel and setPixel on the bitmaps.  I won't go into all the different optimization strategies, but this is certainly a doable solution and it completely bypasses the need for a Canvas.

Comment: With 'for' loops that iterate over the two dimensional arrays of pixels. It looks like from your code sample that you're already familiar with for-loops.